# HeidiSQL won't list my database

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, heidisql

My postgres `yaml` part looking like this:

```
postgres:
    container_name: 'postgres'
    image: postgres:10.1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
      - POSTGRES_DB=myids
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - app-network
```

Then when I am logging in with that credentials using HeidiSQL I cant see my database:
[image]

Any ideas?

Update thanks to this answer I managed to find my database https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1304 using this select:

```
SELECT datname FROM pg_database
WHERE datistemplate = false;
```

Now the question why HeidiSQL won't show that?

Comment: Those are schemas, not databases - those are two very different concepts. With Postgres you connect to **one** database. Once you are connected, you can't switch to a different database. You can only access the schemas _inside_ that database.

Comment: HeidiSQL issues `SELECT nspname FROM pg_catalog.pg_namespace` to retrieve all schemata. And yes, HeidiSQL shows schemata, not databases. That's why the _Databas**e**_ setting in the session manager is not labelled _Databas**es**_ as in MySQL mode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We have to specify the database name in the connection manager, only then will it display the selected database. Please refer to the images below...
[image]

[image][image][image]

There is no provision to view all the databases in PostgreSQL in HeidiSQL, but for MySQL the database name field is optional.

Comment: I did specify the name in the connection manager, but got instead connected to the "postgres" database anyway

Comment: I apologize for the mistake. I'm in fact connected to the correct DB, the name just isn't displayed correctly and instead HeidiSQL shows the name of the connection session from the session manager

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you don't have the star icon selected. Otherwise it will only show the tables marked as favorites